# SQL SERVER USER PERMISSION ON LINUX

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2017, sql-server-on-linux, sql-server-vnext

I am planning to install SQL SERVER 2017 on Redhat Linux with least privilege account without using a root account.

What is the linux permission I need for the account to be able to do the setup as well as the folder permission I need on the SQL Server related folders?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read [Install SQL Server and create a database on Red Hat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-red-hat)?

Comment: @ lad2025, yes I did read the documents but it doesn't explicitly say much about service account and permissions, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: @MAMIR SQL Server on Linux runs under it's own password-less account(created during installation), there is no point to create an individual account for that.

Comment: @LinLeng-MSFT , Thank you. can I get more information on the name of the account, the group it belongs to if any and permission it has?

Answer (score 0):

The installer makes a user and group called mssql that has rw permissions on the related folders.